# How to avoid a same instance of class java is running many times

Tags: java, jsp

I have class named: ReceiptGenerateAgentDAO receiptGenerateAgentDAO =
   new ReceiptGenerateAgentDAO(); this class will be called from a jsp
   page, which has a method and in that i have a for loop which will
   execute for more then 5 min and the issue is I request the jsp to
   call the class and the class started executing,now i reload the jsp
   and again call the class now both the class are running it is not a
   thread,how it is possible and how to resolve it?

```
for (String Key : list) {
        if (!"userDetailsCache".equals(Key)) {
            preparedStatement2.setString(1, Key);
            @Cleanup
            ResultSet rsCreditReceipt = preparedStatement2.executeQuery();
            if (rsCreditReceipt.next()
                    && rsCreditReceipt.getString("SUMMARY_DATE") != null) {
                String exBalance = rsCreditReceipt.getString("balance");
                /** Agent Current Balance */
                preparedStatement3.setString(1,
                        rsCreditReceipt.getString("SUMMARY_DATE"));
                preparedStatement3.setString(2, Key);
                @Cleanup
                ResultSet rsCreditBal = preparedStatement3.executeQuery();
                double creditDebit = Double.parseDouble(exBalance);
                if (rsCreditBal.next()) {
                    if (rsCreditBal.getString("creditdebit") != null) {
                        creditDebit += Double.parseDouble(rsCreditBal
                                .getString("creditdebit"));
                    }
                }
                if (creditDebit < 0) {
                    Element element = EhcacheManager.getUserDetailsCache()
                            .get(Key);
                    UserDetails details = (UserDetails) element
                            .getObjectValue();
                    /** Agent Opening Balance */
                    getZoneDetails(details, connection);
                    receiptGenerateTempDTOs.add(new ReceiptGenerateTempDTO(
                            details.getTerritoryId(), details
                                    .getSatelliteId(), details.getZoneId(),
                            rsCreditReceipt.getString(3),
                            NumericConstants.ZERO, String.valueOf(formatter
                                    .format((creditDebit * (-1)))), time,
                            receiptGenerateAgentDTO.getSelectedUserId(),
                            NumericConstants.ZERO));
                }
            } else {
                /** If no opening balance,only current Balance */
                preparedStatement4.setString(1, Key);
                @Cleanup
                ResultSet rsCreditBal = preparedStatement4.executeQuery();
                if (rsCreditBal.next()) {
                    Element element = EhcacheManager.getUserDetailsCache()
                            .get(Key);
                    UserDetails details = (UserDetails) element
                            .getObjectValue();
                    getZoneDetails(details, connection);
                    receiptGenerateTempDTOs
                            .add(new ReceiptGenerateTempDTO(
                                    details.getTerritoryId(),
                                    details.getSatelliteId(),
                                    details.getZoneId(),
                                    details.getUserId(),
                                    NumericConstants.ZERO,
                                    String.valueOf(formatter.format((Double.parseDouble(rsCreditBal
                                            .getString("creditdebit")) * (-1)))),
                                    time, receiptGenerateAgentDTO
                                            .getSelectedUserId(),
                                    NumericConstants.ZERO));
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(i++);
    }
```

---

Comment: So you need to have it as `Singleton` class to avoid instantiating it more than once.

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: i have update the question with code

Comment: I've done a mild code format but your code seems to have got messed up somewhere in the copy-paste, do you have an indented version?

Comment: no richard i dont have a indented version

Comment: yes i am working in eclipse only

Comment: Then Strg+Shift+F is your friend

Comment: yes i have done it before it will be aligneed in eclipse only not in stackoverflow akku

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Singleton Pattern to create a class which will have only one instance :

```
public class Singleton {
private static Singleton instance = null;

private Singleton() {
    // Is private to be not accessible
}

public static Singleton getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new Singleton();
    }
    return instance;
}
}
```

The if you want to call a method of the singleton class, use :   `Singleton.getInstance.someMethod()`.

Comment: Akkusativobjekt but it is a normal class ,if so i want to use all the class has singleton

Comment: Just wrap your class with the access pattern.

Comment: its possible to close the instance of that class if it is already running

Comment: The Singleton pattern just wraps the (method) access of your class, not more or less. If there would be a close method in your class (with Singleton Pattern) , you could call it like the somMethod() above.

Comment: that is a report class if this is the case many times it will get refresh and all the instance will run. if singleton it will be a huge change for me any other possiblity

Answer (score 0):

Can be solved in many ways..

**Method 1 :**

Change the scope of the class to session Scope.
By this your class will not be Garbage collected after every request. The Class object will be kept until the session expires.

---

**Method 2:**

Change the scope of the class to Singleton. By this you will be creating just one object for the entire user session. You can do this in these steps.

**Step 1:**
Create a static Object of the class, and initialize it with a null value

```
Private Static ClassName staticClassName=null;
```

**Step 2:**
Block the constructor so that ClassName obj= new ClassName() wont get you a new Object.

```
private ClassName() {....}
```

**Step 3**
Create another method findClassObject() that return the object of the class

```
public static ClassName findClassObject(){
if(staticClassName==null){
staticClassName= new ClassName() ; //since the constructor method is called from within the class, it returns a new Object of the Class ClassName
}
return staticClassName;
}
```

**Setp 4**

Initialize the class Object using this, which will always return the same object.

```
ClassName obj= ClassName.findClassObject();
```